# UserForm1.Show gives error 9

Tags: vba, excel

I created an ActiveX button to open a form using the line

```
UserForm1.Show
```

but when I click the button I get error 9 (subscript out of range). The form exists and the name of the form is UserForm1. When I debug, it highlights the line UserForm1.Show but I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Edit:

The initialize code is below

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Let list1 = Array()
For j = 0 To 67
list1(j) = Sheet2.Cells(2+j, 1)
Next
Let colors = Array("Blue", "Black", "Gold", "Green")
ComboBox1.List = list1
ListBox1.List = colors
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you load the form before trying to show it `Load UserForm1`? Do you have code on the form (for example on `initialize` or `activate`)? If so, please append the code to your question. Do you have any linked sources  on the form (for example a listbox with a data source calling upon a broken named range etc.)?

Comment: In most cases of this type of error, the `userform`.show` code is not the error but the `userform_initialize` is in error, since there is an error in the `initialize` code, the debug will stop at `userform1.show`

Comment: @Colleen - can you share code in UserForm_Initialize()

Comment: I have added the requested code

Comment: `0` is out of bounds for your `list1` array. See my answer/explanation below.

Comment: @Jeeped - you can use `Let` in a conventional VBA sub, just that's there's no point to doing it (as far as I know):  `Dim v$(1 To 3): Let v(1) = "Hello"` or `Dim dbl#: Let dbl = 3.1`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - Thanks for that. I'll have to do some investigating on my own.

Comment: It's never a waste of time if you learned something. (cannot comment in a deleted post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not properly declared your `list1` variable.

ALWAYS declare all of your variables, and in the case of arrays, when possible to dimension at initialization, do so. Or, leave them as variant and you can assign using the `Array(...)` function (like you do with `colors`). But for `list1` array, you've initialized it as an empty array with an upper-bound of -1, so the very first assignment to `list1(0)` will fail, as `0` is out of bounds. Instead, since you know this array needs to have len = 68, just dimension it that way with the `Dim` statement:

```
Option Explicit  ' # Enforce variable declaration!!
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim list1(67) 
Dim colors() 
Dim j as Long

colors = Array("Blue", "Black", "Gold", "Green")

For j = 0 to 67
    list1(j) = ...
```

(If you need to resize later, you can use `ReDim` and `ReDim Preserve` statements).

Answer (score 0):

So I know this is an old post but I started working on a project and I came across this after encountering the same problem.

What I needed was code to fill a ListBox when the userform initialized and at first, I tried using arrays and collections to do it which gave error (9) and brought me here. Then I just took the array out and added the data straight into the ListBox. You could do this with a ComboBox as well. See below. David Zemens answer works but you can't resize an already dimensioned array so you have to make the array bigger then what you could use wich just adds empty spaces to the ListBox.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 'Get headers for List Box
Dim colCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer

colCount = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'How many headers to work with

For i = 1 To colCount
 lBox_headers.AddItem Cells(1, i) 'Add headers to this listbox
Next i

End Sub
```

This code is just grabbing column headers and adding them to a list box. Hope it helps someone else who finds themselves here.